# How to listen to DB changes in Azure Cosmos DB from Node App

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Azure CosmosDB provides changed feed feature.
One can listen to DB changes and run business logic in response. 
Is there a way this can be achieved in a Node App? 
There is a change feed processor library, but I didn't come across any node SDK to use it. 
If any one can provide few pointers how this can be achieved it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no equivalent of the Change Feed processor library for Node.

However the Node.js SDK allows you to query the change feed itself manually. You can find an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#can-i-read-change-feed-using-javascript

This however means that you will have to write the automated process yourself and you can't be notified only when there is a change. You will have to keep previous and next states and compare what's new and what's not.

You can also achieve automated change feed processing using the Azure Functions trigger which can be used in Node.js (thanks Matias). You can find more info on that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#using-azure-functions

Also this link has a CosmosDB binding example in js (double thanks Matias): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#trigger---javascript-example

Comment: To add to Nick's answer, the Cosmos DB Trigger in Functions can be used in Node.js

Comment: Oh is that not clear from my answer? That's why I added it, because it can be used in Node.

Comment: Maybe you can add this link, it points to the official JS sample of the trigger, then you have the complete usecase :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#trigger---javascript-example

Comment: Thanks for sharing the trigger example Matias. So I create trigger JSON which has ''connectionStringSetting" pointing to endpoint exposed by node app ? Also how do I apply the trigger JSON to cosmos DB?